# how to split a continuous variable in linear model

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I wonder to know what is the better way to split-up a continuous variable in order to avoid slopes in residuals

```
require(tidyverse)

data <- mtcars %>% select (disp, hp)
data_splitted <- mtcars %>% select (disp, hp) %>%
mutate(
    disp170 = ifelse(disp  < 170, disp, 0)
  , disp500 = ifelse(disp  < 170, 0, disp - 170)
  , disp = NULL
)
data_capped <- mtcars %>% select (disp, hp) %>%
mutate(
    disp170 = ifelse(disp  < 170, disp, 0)
  , disp500 = ifelse(disp  < 170, 0, disp)
  , disp = NULL
)


lm <- lm(hp ~ disp , data = data)
lm_splitted <- lm (hp ~ disp170 + disp500 , data = data_splitted)
lm_capped <- lm (hp ~ disp170 + disp500 , data = data_capped)

summary(lm)
plot(lm$residuals ~ data$disp)
summary(lm_splitted)
plot(lm_splitted$residuals ~ data_splitted$disp500)
summary(lm_capped)
plot(lm_capped$residuals ~ data_capped$disp500)
```

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent segmented regression? See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/segmented/versions/0.5-3.0/topics/segmented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My own view is that we should formulate models which answer the question(s) we are interested in, rather than torture the predictor variables until they confess.

When you fit a model like lm(hp ~ disp, data=...), you are essentially assuming that horsepower (hp) tends to either increase or decrease linearly as displacement (disp) increases and you are interested in estimating the rate of increase/decrease from the data. (In this model, you are treating disp as a continuous variable). The model answers questions such as: Does hp tend to increase/decrease with disp and if so, at what rate?

Let's say now that instead of working with the continuous version of the predictor displacement, you are going to work with a binary version of this predictor, defined like this:

```
disp.binary = 1 if disp > observed mean value of disp in the data
disp.binary = 0 otherwise
```

In other words, disp.binary keeps track of whether or not displacement is bigger than average.

We can now fit the model lm(hp ~ disp.binary, data = ...) to the data but this model will answer a different question: Do cars with a displacement which is bigger than average tend to have a larger/smaller horsepower than cars with a displacement which is not bigger than average?

Of course, in practice people discretize predictor variables all the time, sometimes not realizing that not only does this lead to a loss of information but also to answering different questions based on their models.

If you have to discretize a predictor variable, you should at least do so in a way which ensures that you are still answering relevant questions. Some people discretize variables using cut-offs pulled out from the literature or inspired by other subject-matter considerations. Others use data-driven cut-offs like the observed mean of the variable to be discretized or the observed quantiles. The problem with data-driven cut-offs is that they are not portable across similar studies, since they reflect the idiosyncrasies of the data collected in the study at hand.

If you are contemplating discretization of a predictor variable simply because some of the assumptions underlying your current model are violated by the data, there are better options available to you. For example, consider a more flexible model which allows the effect of the predictor to be nonlinear rather than linear or perhaps consider transforming the predictor before including it in your model.